# Semantic similarity between words A and B : Dependency on frequency of A and B in corpus?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

**Background :**

Given a corpus I want to train it with an implementation of word2wec (Gensim).

Want to understand if the final similarity between 2 tokens is dependent on the frequency of A and B in the corpus *(all contexts preserved)*, or agnostic of it.

*Example*: 
(May not be ideal, but using it to elaborate the problem statement)

Suppose word 'A' is being used in 3 different contexts within the corpus :

```
Context 1 : 1000 times
Context 2 : 50000 times
Context 3 : 50000 times
```

'B' is being used in 2 different contexts :

```
Context 1 : 300 times 
Context 5 : 1000 time
```

**Question :**

If I change the frequency of 'A' in my corpus (ensuring no context is lost, i.e. 'A' is still being used at least once in all the contexts as in the original corpus), is the similarity between A snd B going to be the same ?

New distribution of 'A' across contexts

```
 Context 1 : 5 times
 Context 2 : 10 times
 Context 3 : 5000 times
```

Any leads appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that (#translate to gut feeling , not mathematics) :

The similarity will be computed from how often those two words are near to each other, or used in the same context.

Provided you go from there:

If these two words are in fact similar, the more often they are used => the more training data you have => the better the model => the closer they will be.

If you have more context were those two words are used, then their relationship will be closer.

However , if they appear less often across the corpus but more often together, their relationship will be tighter as well.

So it's more of a (frequency_same_context)/(frequency_overall).
If you don't change that , you should be fine I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

Gensim implements two word vector models:

1. Skip-gram
2. CBOW

The difference between the two is on how the featurisation and labels are used to train the word vector model.

Both models are trained on token contexts to autoencode a token into a continuous semantic vector space.

## skip-gram

Inputs for training are context window n-grams while the predicted label is the nth token.

If we used a bigram context window, the input vector would use tokens;

```
[Token_(n-2), Token_(n-1), Token_(n+1), Token_(n+2)]
```

And the label to predict would be

```
Token_n
```

## CBOW

Inputs for training are context window n-grams while the predicted label is the nth token.

If we used a bigram context window, the input vector would use the token;

```
Token_n
```

And the label to predict would be

```
[Token_(n-2), Token_(n-1), Token_(n+1), Token_(n+2)]
```

## what's the purpose?

Obviously this is a gross oversimplification, but it helps us ask, what does the word vector model do?

What's the purpose of the word vector model implemented in gensim?

The two models encode *semantic context* for a given token.

So asking how similar words are in the model *should be proportional to the contexts they were trained on*.

## TL;DR

The WV models encode word context in a  representation.

So the similarity of words is not proportional to their counts but to the contexts they appear in.

Answer (score 0):

The similarity will definitely change if you've "thinned out" the number of example contexts for one word, but not others.

Word2Vec relies on having many, diverse examples of words' usage. The training process only considers single examples of co-occurrences at a time. (In the popular skip-gram mode, just single `context-word -> target-word` examples.).

Training repeatedly presents a single context to the neural-network, checks the networks' response along some small subset of paths that are interesting, and slightly nudges the network to do better – by changing both the network's internal weights, and the 'projection weights' that define a word's vector.

It is the aggregate effect of all those updates, over many iterations, that ends up pushing each word's vector to a useful place, compared to other vectors. (It is a "tug-of-war" between improving some examples, and improving others.)

Anything which changes the mix of examples used will change the final results. In particular, if there are fewer examples of word `A` overall, less overall training time will be spent making the model perform well on contexts including `A`. Its final position, and related weights, will be more influenced by other words' more numerous examples.

Also, slimming down the examples of `A` also practically changes its co-occurrence rates with all words it is ever co-trained with. Fewer `A` contexts mean the number of `A -> B` and `B -> A` contexts will also change, which will also change word `B`'s final position. And that goes for all other words `C`, `D`, etc that co-occur with `A`, and especially so when some contexts are thinned more than others. (As, in your example of `A`'s new distribution, 'context 2' appears 1/5000th as frequently, but 'context 3' appears 1/10th as frequently.)

Note that there is a frequent-word-downsampling feature in most Word2Vec implementations, usually controlled with a parameter named `sample`, which intentionally *discards* many appearances of very-frequent words. This does, intentionally, change the relative frequencies of words in the training corpus.

And compared to no-downsampling, a well-chosen value here tends to both speed training *and* improve the quality of the final word-vectors. Why? Once you have hundreds or thousands of diverse examples of a frequent word, the extra marginal example isn't helping improve that word very much - but it *is* taking more time, and a higher-proportion of training time overall, improving the model for those frequent words. And those words' tiny-improvements, over many examples, are necessarily per the process described above trading off against improvements to the more numerous words with rarer examples. Discarding some of the "over-frequent" words lets the other words have more relative influence on the model's final state, and indeed even effectively shrinks the effective context-distances between rarer words (when the more-frequent intervening words get dropped).